# Insert multiple row to sql server

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to insert multiple row into a tabel. But always get 500 Internal server error when I insert it. Can anyone help me what's wrong with my code?

Here's my controller

```
  $data = array(
  'NumberOfPlacement' => $_POST['hidden_total'],
  'ExpectedWorkStartDate' => $_POST['hidden_workdate'],
  'CreatedDate' => date("Y-m-d")
);
 $res= $this->hire_model()->InsertData('dbo.RequisitionTable', $data);
if ($res) {
  echo json_encode(array('status' => true));
}else
echo json_encode(array('status'=>false));
}
```

My Model

```
public function InsertData($tabelName, $data){
$res = $this->db->insert($tabelName, $data);
return $res;
}
```

Here's my data. Its contain 2 data

```
 array(4) {
  ["NumberOfPlacement"]=>
  array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "3"
 }
 ["ExpectedWorkStartDate"]=>
 array(2) {
 [0]=>
 string(10) "2019-09-24"
 [1]=>
 string(10) "2019-09-25"
 }
 ["CreatedDate"]=>
 string(10) "2019-09-19"
 }
```

Comment: you can use `insert_batch()` for inserting multiple record

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Try This :  $data = array(
  'NumberOfPlacement' => serialize($_POST['hidden_total']),
  'ExpectedWorkStartDate' => serialize($_POST['hidden_workdate']),
  'CreatedDate' => date("Y-m-d")
);

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
$data = array(
  'NumberOfPlacement' => serialize($_POST['hidden_total']),
  'ExpectedWorkStartDate' => serialize($_POST['hidden_workdate']),
  'CreatedDate' => date("Y-m-d")
);
```

When you retrieve data please try unserialize().

Answer (score 0):

did you load your hire_model model properly.. just check it .. and if NO
replace

```
 $res= $this->hire_model()->InsertData('dbo.RequisitionTable', $data);
```

to

```
$res= $this->load->mdoel('hire_model');
 $this->hire_model->InsertData('dbo.RequisitionTable', $data);
```

and re formate your data to insert into db like

```
$data = array(
 array(
  'NumberOfPlacement' => $_POST['hidden_total'],
  'ExpectedWorkStartDate' => $_POST['hidden_workdate'],
  'CreatedDate' => date("Y-m-d")
 ),
 array(
  'NumberOfPlacement' => $_POST['hidden_total'],
  'ExpectedWorkStartDate' => $_POST['hidden_workdate'],
  'CreatedDate' => date("Y-m-d")
 )
);
```

than at you hire_model InsertData method:

```
public function InsertData($tabelName = '', $data = array()){ 
   $this->db->insert_batch($tabelName, $data); // insert_batch is codeigniter method to insert multiple data
}
```